# How to find which mods are inactive

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I have a pretty large collection of mods, however recently I have noticed that not all of my mods were active.

Is there a way to find which mods are inactive?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using a launcher/modpack you have to test every mod if its working. make sure all of the mods are in the correct version of minecraft. for example, if you have forge 1.8.8 you can't use a 1.9 mod

Answer (score 0):

Check that they end in zip or jar in the mods folders. Also some launchers such as the FTB launcher allow you to edit the mod list before launching the game. Hope this helps